# Update is not working in Access VBA - ADODB.Recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

I try update recordset by update argument and code run good but a updating record is still same.

Code:

```
With mMails
    .LEVEL1 = cTagLevel1
    .MAIN_TAG = cTagLevel2
    .DETAILED_TAG = cTagLevel3
    .FIELD_TAG = cTagField
    .INSIGHT = cTagInsight
    .BRANCH = cTagBranch
    .DataSource.Commit
End With
```

And Commit Sub:

```
Public Sub Commit()
    mRst.Update
End Sub
```

And Connection:

```
Set mRst = New ADODB.Recordset
Set mRst.SOURCE = pCmd
mRst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
mRst.CursorType = adOpenStatic
mRst.LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
mRst.Open
If Not (pAccessMode = AccessMode_ReadOnly) Then
    Set mCn = pCmd.ActiveConnection
End If
Set mRst.ActiveConnection = Nothing
```

All values with mMails are correct but update doesn't work. What I doing wrong? When I tried use UpdateBatch the update want change whole row and not only selected...

Sry for my English :) and thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I see you use a static cursor: "A static copy of a set of records that you can use to find data or generate reports. Additions, changes, or deletions by other users are not visible."

I think you should use a dynamic cursor: "Additions, changes, and deletions by other users are visible, and all types of movement through the Recordset are allowed."

Note the word "copy" in the description of the static cursor: you are making changes to a copy, but the copy is not saved in the database.

You also may need to change the `CursorLocation` property to `adUseServer`: "If the CursorLocation property is set to `adUseClient`, the only valid setting for the `CursorType` property is `adOpenStatic`".

See also: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_ref_recordset.asp

Comment: Thanks Paul for answer! After change the `CursorLocation` I can't open a form... When I back to `adUseClient` all is right. I don't know why. I read about `LockType` and I even changed to `asLockOptymistic` but still the same problem with update. When I tried use UpdateBatch the code want change whole row with autonumeric columns and I had error  window with text "You can't update ID column..." Update: When I used Update too it's the same error: "You can't update ID column..." :(